# x509 certificate with excluded subtree violation issue

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, openssl

I would like to use self-signed x509 certificates in our testing environment so I followed the process described in Ivan Ristic's "**OpenSSL Cookbook**". Great resource. I decided to go the private CA route as well.

However, Chrome complains that my site/https endpoint is unsecured with a "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error. openssl s_client also raises a verify error:num=48:**excluded subtree violation**. Firefox gives me a "SEC_ERROR_CERT_NOT_IN_NAME_SPACE" error page.

I'm stumped as to why the excluded subtree violation? With my limited knowledge (first time using private CA functionality), I am probably wrong thinking my host.cnf has SAN hostnames that are permitted via the nameConstraints in my root-ca.conf?  I appreciate any insights, corrections to my misunderstanding of openssl config files.

rfc5280 section "4.2.1.10.  Name Constraints" states that:

> DNS name restrictions are expressed as host.example.com.  Any DNS
>      name that can be constructed by simply adding zero or more labels to
>      the left-hand side of the name satisfies the name constraint.  For
>      example, www.host.example.com would satisfy the constraint but
>      host1.example.com would not.

But I'm seeing many examples of SAN, nameConstraints which are using the leading dot notation - so I tried two DNS nameConstraints in my root-ca.conf.  I'm desperate so I will assume either can be correct...

Gory details:
I set up my root-ca, sub-ca config files, created the corresponding CSRs, root-ca.crt, sub-ca.crt, via the following commands:

```
(on the target machine - but I haven't found any docs saying this is required)
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out host-private.key 2048
openssl req -new -key host-private.key -out host.csr -passin pass:XXXX -config host.cnf
```

Copied the host.csr over to my CA environment. I ran the following commands to create the root CA cert:

```
openssl req -new -config root-ca.conf -out root-ca.csr -keyout private/root-ca.key
openssl ca -selfsign -config root-ca.conf -in root-ca.csr -out root-ca.crt -extensions ca_ext
```

to create the intermediate/subordinate CA cert:

```
openssl req -new -config sub-ca.conf -out sub-ca.csr -keyout private/sub-ca.key
openssl ca -config root-ca.conf -in sub-ca.csr -out sub-ca.crt -extensions sub_ca_ext
```

Then, created the host certificate:

```
openssl ca -config sub-ca.conf -in host.csr -out host.crt -extensions server_ext
```

I created a chain certificate for deployment into my nginx env. host.csr + sub-ca.crt + root-ca.crt

I also added the root-ca.crt into my host's CA trust store. I'm using nginx to serve as an SSL/TLS terminator reverse proxy for several internal services via the ngx_http_proxy module.
I also added the generated root-ca.crt into my Chrome installation's CE trust store.
The site information as displayed by Chrome has the root-ca, sub-ca, host certificates correctly in the certificate hierarchy.

host.cnf:

```
[req]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = dn
req_extensions = ext
# the use of -passin overrides this 
input_password = PASSPHRASE
[dn]
CN = rt168openmbee.serc.stevens.edu
emailAddress = shespelt@stevens.edu
O = SERC
L = Hoboken
ST = NJ
C = US
[ext]
subjectAltName = DNS:rt168openmbee.serc.stevens.edu,IP:155.246.39.32
```

root-ca.conf:

```
[default]
name                    = root-ca
domain_suffix           = serc.stevens.edu 
aia_url                 = http://$name.$domain_suffix/$name.crt
crl_url                 = http://$name.$domain_suffix/$name.crl
ocsp_url                = http://ocsp.$name.$domain_suffix:9080
default_ca              = ca_default
name_opt                = utf8,esc_ctrl,multiline,lname,align

[ca_dn]
countryName             = "US"
organizationName        = "SERC"
commonName              = "Root CA"

[ca_default]
home                    = .
database                = $home/db/index
serial                  = $home/db/serial
crlnumber               = $home/db/crlnumber
certificate             = $home/$name.crt
private_key             = $home/private/$name.key
RANDFILE                = $home/private/random
new_certs_dir           = $home/certs
unique_subject          = no
copy_extensions         = none
default_days            = 3650
default_crl_days        = 365
default_md              = sha256
policy                  = policy_c_o_match

[policy_c_o_match]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[req]
default_bits            = 4096
encrypt_key             = yes
default_md              = sha256
utf8                    = yes
string_mask             = utf8only
prompt                  = no
distinguished_name      = ca_dn
req_extensions          = ca_ext

[ca_ext]
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:true
keyUsage                = critical,keyCertSign,cRLSign
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash

[sub_ca_ext]
authorityInfoAccess     = @issuer_info
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:true,pathlen:0
crlDistributionPoints   = @crl_info
extendedKeyUsage        = clientAuth,serverAuth
keyUsage                = critical,keyCertSign,cRLSign
nameConstraints         = @name_constraints
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash

[crl_info]
URI.0                   = $crl_url

[issuer_info]
caIssuers;URI.0         = $aia_url
OCSP;URI.0              = $ocsp_url

[name_constraints]
permitted;DNS.0=serc.stevens.edu
permitted;DNS.1=.serc.stevens.edu
permitted;IP.0=155.246.39.0/255.255.255.0
excluded;IP.1=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
excluded;IP.2=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

[ocsp_ext]
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:false
extendedKeyUsage        = OCSPSigning
noCheck                 = yes
keyUsage                = critical,digitalSignature
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
```

sub-ca.conf:

```
[default]
name                    = sub-ca
domain_suffix           = serc.stevens.edu
aia_url                 = http://$name.$domain_suffix/$name.crt
crl_url                 = http://$name.$domain_suffix/$name.crl
ocsp_url                = http://ocsp.$name.$domain_suffix:9081
default_ca              = ca_default
name_opt                = utf8,esc_ctrl,multiline,lname,align

[ca_dn]
countryName             = "US"
organizationName        = "SERC"
commonName              = "Sub CA"

[ca_default]
home                    = .
database                = $home/db/index
serial                  = $home/db/serial
crlnumber               = $home/db/crlnumber
certificate             = $home/$name.crt
private_key             = $home/private/$name.key
RANDFILE                = $home/private/random
new_certs_dir           = $home/certs
unique_subject          = no
copy_extensions         = copy
default_days            = 365
default_crl_days        = 30
default_md              = sha256
policy                  = policy_c_o_match

[policy_c_o_match]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[req]
default_bits            = 2048
encrypt_key             = yes
default_md              = sha256
utf8                    = yes
string_mask             = utf8only
prompt                  = no
distinguished_name      = ca_dn

[server_ext]
authorityInfoAccess     = @issuer_info
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:false
crlDistributionPoints   = @crl_info
extendedKeyUsage        = clientAuth,serverAuth
keyUsage                = critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash

[client_ext]
authorityInfoAccess     = @issuer_info
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:false
crlDistributionPoints   = @crl_info
extendedKeyUsage        = clientAuth
keyUsage                = critical,digitalSignature
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash

[crl_info]
URI.0                   = $crl_url

[issuer_info]
caIssuers;URI.0         = $aia_url
OCSP;URI.0              = $ocsp_url

[ocsp_ext]
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:false
extendedKeyUsage        = OCSPSigning
keyUsage                = critical,digitalSignature
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
```

using openssl s_client -showcerts -connect, here are the retrieved certs (saved PEM certs run through openssl x509 -text ...).
host certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            29:d9:fb:61:7a:0f:ba:c3:51:28:a3:05:14:df:8a:b1
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = SERC, CN = Sub CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 18 19:52:13 2019 GMT
            Not After : Jul 17 19:52:13 2020 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = NJ, O = SERC, CN = rt168openmbee.serc.stevens.edu, emailAddress = shespelt@stevens.edu
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b9:19:1f:2b:2a:54:bc:7a:78:1c:13:33:09:8e:
                    12:e1:b5:f8:7c:58:f8:29:7e:b4:45:45:6b:5a:3f:
                    ac:41:f6:d6:bf:4a:08:77:a6:a0:94:dd:26:68:ed:
                    8a:ec:fc:e9:3e:db:98:45:0c:cf:8a:09:d6:46:14:
                    a7:bb:d2:f0:da:dd:db:7c:ed:31:7b:20:f7:7d:f0:
                    f9:13:1a:45:1b:ab:90:79:a7:d7:60:d2:94:70:0e:
                    79:4c:03:23:c0:b6:f7:dc:93:b4:c7:eb:6e:69:f1:
                    58:6c:14:07:98:4e:56:9d:01:39:d6:a1:be:da:a5:
                    76:83:aa:68:30:65:51:23:96:99:fe:05:9c:a7:61:
                    64:30:b1:f6:38:33:70:6d:8b:25:ce:d9:93:6e:b0:
                    5e:84:e8:71:4b:55:62:64:f1:6b:b4:ed:7b:dd:b7:
                    d9:b2:4a:24:29:bb:3b:ad:59:cc:4d:fb:84:6a:91:
                    45:e7:f1:cc:21:48:40:42:83:03:1e:07:6d:3f:c2:
                    a6:bf:8f:76:db:f8:9c:a2:a9:88:71:81:f5:d6:48:
                    d9:17:d9:0d:bb:9d:c5:24:bb:d8:58:93:85:1c:5f:
                    a4:39:df:8f:d6:9a:2a:2f:9c:34:bb:28:f0:87:fe:
                    df:9d:41:8a:0b:f6:c5:a3:0c:4c:6c:e1:f4:a6:89:
                    23:c1
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://sub-ca.serc.stevens.edu/sub-ca.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.sub-ca.serc.stevens.edu:9081

            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:FB:BB:13:DE:9C:C7:5F:B4:07:2C:03:3D:35:59:CC:B4:9F:8F:FA:1F

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://sub-ca.serc.stevens.edu/sub-ca.crl

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                4F:60:83:45:A3:32:DB:C4:5C:AD:C1:BD:69:09:AF:E2:55:13:1A:6A
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:rt168openmbee.serc.stevens.edu, IP Address:155.246.39.32
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         07:d1:b6:ab:5d:b4:8a:f7:77:3c:57:06:f3:7c:69:a9:fa:85:
         d0:04:b6:3b:24:2b:32:9f:31:4e:33:3b:a9:ed:d8:3e:8a:cf:
         aa:19:be:84:86:42:86:9c:d3:c4:a6:35:2e:87:b5:10:40:d2:
         05:92:13:e1:e6:00:cc:42:f9:55:ff:14:ba:3e:0e:d8:3c:9b:
         d6:47:19:27:61:d3:c1:a4:9f:a9:80:c7:ae:68:c1:bf:a1:3c:
         fd:c6:cc:df:16:4e:0b:ca:22:3e:d1:5f:b6:9f:ee:38:84:3b:
         65:4d:86:d5:f3:df:03:7a:e1:13:ad:1e:62:8c:ad:ca:3c:d4:
         78:89:8a:91:c9:a8:85:58:fa:78:49:ff:94:b5:37:68:72:89:
         18:94:d7:08:ec:62:40:a5:35:1d:93:2c:7b:bf:b7:f1:b4:0f:
         57:a7:17:69:8d:fb:a4:7d:1f:7b:bd:8c:f6:32:a9:6a:e4:04:
         64:89:05:55:ee:43:cf:a3:51:67:35:6c:84:16:62:d3:6e:57:
         de:0b:e9:fb:e3:11:a7:ed:94:9e:1e:ef:ec:5f:c4:03:33:cf:
         0c:00:5c:8b:9f:ad:4e:b2:89:01:9f:be:49:9d:51:b8:2f:ba:
         f3:9d:70:80:69:e3:bf:95:d6:a3:07:ee:fa:8b:84:ac:78:50:
         7c:f3:08:0c
```

intermediate CA certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            4e:79:79:cc:2e:ca:7e:42:21:43:8a:fa:ba:fa:6f:cb
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = SERC, CN = Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 18 19:49:50 2019 GMT
            Not After : Jul 15 19:49:50 2029 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = SERC, CN = Sub CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:be:90:03:fa:85:91:b7:0a:72:6c:0c:81:aa:6d:
                    19:c1:d6:40:a5:f9:c5:28:35:ce:d6:e1:70:ea:eb:
                    80:54:2b:ad:87:e5:67:b1:6c:94:df:14:e7:97:9f:
                    1d:00:a3:db:96:48:e1:76:6f:06:bf:3d:27:f8:62:
                    74:90:75:95:3c:f2:5d:40:d4:1b:11:61:f0:52:db:
                    9a:d9:7f:4e:04:76:7f:fa:4e:c2:f2:00:fc:79:fb:
                    0c:51:aa:b8:39:5a:9c:73:b5:1f:04:cd:76:5c:7b:
                    a2:4b:41:3e:14:47:e9:d4:b1:b5:46:3b:05:05:99:
                    cc:63:1e:d8:1c:3d:4a:5a:b4:23:23:3e:39:8a:78:
                    05:1a:44:ba:fd:a4:b5:98:05:a4:e0:b8:d8:f1:3a:
                    0a:09:54:2d:4d:db:09:df:88:1c:b4:73:a5:a7:41:
                    5d:f8:a8:ec:fc:52:b1:6f:36:22:1c:3e:e7:66:93:
                    90:a7:dc:32:50:21:60:31:57:51:09:76:50:15:f7:
                    fc:4e:b9:05:ae:b6:93:2e:f4:b0:44:aa:3c:73:a7:
                    1c:c5:87:d9:54:81:f3:97:42:df:08:77:0b:5d:dd:
                    01:04:be:5e:1a:94:57:4b:82:65:71:91:3b:ad:58:
                    82:b7:55:e7:c9:7e:ed:fd:59:0f:83:48:1a:33:d4:
                    95:c1
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://root-ca.serc.stevens.edu/root-ca.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.root-ca.serc.stevens.edu:9080

            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:F1:86:94:29:A7:F0:AF:A2:CF:CC:A2:A6:D4:63:B1:02:0A:36:7E:83

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://root-ca.serc.stevens.edu/root-ca.crl

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Name Constraints: 
                Permitted:
                  DNS:serc.stevens.edu
                  DNS:.serc.stevens.edu
                  IP:155.246.39.0/255.255.255.0
                Excluded:
                  IP:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
                  IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                FB:BB:13:DE:9C:C7:5F:B4:07:2C:03:3D:35:59:CC:B4:9F:8F:FA:1F
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ab:93:26:fa:85:ae:72:fa:e3:2d:65:9a:10:a5:c8:cc:e2:1c:
         c6:4d:40:53:80:c2:6f:67:24:4e:29:23:b9:75:6e:2f:7f:ce:
         7e:fb:2c:64:e8:e6:90:13:2d:39:da:13:3f:a9:71:5b:72:b1:
         3b:11:e5:aa:98:e6:cc:47:a7:95:dc:7a:c0:27:2f:52:1e:08:
         1f:34:b5:ab:1d:16:53:89:d4:b4:8a:d9:f7:ca:4d:7a:5a:bc:
         9a:16:ed:45:5d:18:2a:50:0b:57:12:ea:23:8a:b8:f1:2b:26:
         5b:1a:e8:7b:35:37:de:22:8f:cf:ae:f6:4f:7f:3e:88:0b:21:
         40:40:46:53:ad:83:6a:3a:26:ba:0e:28:ba:0c:8d:04:56:e3:
         59:d5:7d:13:06:d2:89:b1:5c:50:0c:54:60:09:bc:22:b8:96:
         e8:42:8c:a6:dd:47:86:6f:16:bd:a9:45:3f:b6:f1:4d:58:82:
         cf:e9:e2:e2:be:2b:2d:97:e5:0d:df:24:09:96:95:1d:1a:08:
         94:87:73:6c:61:1a:70:36:ae:55:79:a8:ae:58:66:0d:2a:94:
         32:27:91:bb:0a:5c:2f:64:b8:fe:a2:5f:3d:f7:d9:66:a9:2a:
         e4:6b:9b:7f:66:ba:7a:61:e6:57:4f:c8:8b:5c:74:d7:0b:db:
         a3:cb:d2:97:50:95:6f:34:64:24:ce:7a:0b:c3:dd:3a:7c:81:
         d1:48:5e:74:af:7f:9c:fc:73:3b:01:b9:a9:d7:67:87:7b:81:
         b0:99:9b:a5:29:1d:97:bb:70:61:48:32:13:e8:20:da:f5:7a:
         96:2b:c0:04:1f:b2:27:a3:cb:35:a0:63:08:e3:5b:8e:ae:87:
         60:c9:85:9e:b7:4a:a7:12:8f:81:3b:7d:5b:00:05:be:54:bd:
         49:4e:1c:73:0e:c7:51:27:40:82:63:e4:48:d5:94:f3:63:53:
         a1:84:5c:ca:3a:91:94:ca:23:de:65:48:5b:ff:7e:e6:79:8b:
         a1:bf:c0:2d:9f:91:b5:c5:66:3c:58:e8:b8:e9:8f:81:18:cb:
         7e:eb:46:4b:59:5d:d1:34:74:3f:92:c4:0d:9e:4a:ec:25:f4:
         48:f4:d8:c9:a1:8f:72:2f:a5:8b:a2:14:16:f1:84:41:9b:df:
         85:99:62:af:50:ab:c0:4d:4c:a9:7a:d0:31:24:4f:04:00:e3:
         16:bb:53:08:fa:66:8b:d5:15:2b:22:62:ac:64:38:c2:2f:c0:
         fa:ad:a1:be:b6:67:f6:f6:ac:af:a4:33:ea:4a:a0:8d:49:ad:
         35:3c:6f:ae:b3:b6:a0:e6:84:df:32:36:46:73:48:26:28:a2:
         10:9a:d2:2c:85:48:d7:d4
```

root CA certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            4e:79:79:cc:2e:ca:7e:42:21:43:8a:fa:ba:fa:6f:ca
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = SERC, CN = Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 18 19:47:30 2019 GMT
            Not After : Jul 15 19:47:30 2029 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = SERC, CN = Root CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c7:6a:ca:cb:b6:3b:23:63:f4:21:32:37:a6:b8:
                    ed:34:0a:06:38:06:7a:cf:3a:0a:6e:36:ef:81:d0:
                    01:2d:e7:ea:dc:d9:46:d7:45:f3:ed:84:ed:7e:20:
                    6a:e2:00:34:43:4e:2a:fc:2b:53:ef:d2:af:1e:25:
                    c9:ed:e0:34:d0:9a:03:c2:50:16:46:96:89:cb:6d:
                    43:b4:17:61:49:07:53:85:62:d6:27:b5:0a:b0:87:
                    3b:b6:e3:ba:f7:b9:35:77:37:bb:ae:a8:7e:04:0f:
                    54:e2:b3:26:b0:3f:65:01:27:fc:dc:ac:b6:3a:a4:
                    d0:ea:6a:d2:f5:c5:7c:be:43:0f:41:d1:9d:1c:1c:
                    61:e1:ba:af:03:95:30:10:a9:3d:52:64:ce:70:40:
                    bd:dc:0d:53:35:00:c1:e9:e1:68:fd:f5:d5:d1:a1:
                    e4:c7:c7:22:fb:56:6f:a6:e1:ea:48:e8:61:fb:8c:
                    76:28:8a:4e:18:84:ab:f3:9b:d5:49:7c:04:40:15:
                    83:4d:26:2b:33:92:84:7e:f2:75:1b:0b:4c:d6:54:
                    c3:f2:4a:9f:13:72:ab:9c:92:a4:42:77:99:00:25:
                    91:c1:b6:87:bd:fa:f1:07:f0:ce:72:0f:3c:be:bc:
                    79:58:f6:8b:6e:07:bc:5d:ee:23:be:0d:d5:d6:91:
                    22:f4:73:1b:4f:5f:cc:82:87:57:61:50:96:8c:69:
                    0b:ae:f7:40:47:7c:62:4e:2e:77:3e:8c:f1:41:7d:
                    e8:64:d5:bf:24:36:99:bb:0c:46:0e:28:7b:52:95:
                    7d:b8:f2:e5:91:0d:07:ea:cb:9c:9d:08:dd:1f:e2:
                    3a:02:6a:5b:36:d1:ff:b9:0f:a4:08:ed:12:38:7a:
                    0b:a1:68:7e:be:b1:bb:90:e2:6a:9f:33:8f:d4:d2:
                    8b:ba:84:db:f9:c6:d7:94:19:d5:cd:db:ce:b3:ba:
                    53:36:51:9a:16:12:57:f9:16:27:1e:23:3b:09:c0:
                    2b:d8:f3:cf:d7:d2:ec:2d:b0:fd:bf:dc:85:7d:cb:
                    9d:cc:e1:70:0d:2a:fd:43:4f:48:3d:89:09:33:2e:
                    6b:e8:f0:ba:ca:21:9c:32:79:a2:64:e1:dc:75:8b:
                    ed:0b:32:50:5b:b1:b5:0b:11:7a:d4:f0:d9:df:f7:
                    61:04:4a:c5:41:c7:0e:cb:e5:c7:1a:3c:6e:7b:63:
                    8b:bd:e5:f2:99:c8:2e:5c:e4:ed:a0:1d:b4:c1:64:
                    b8:71:27:23:23:2f:93:54:b4:d8:99:b5:a4:35:7b:
                    dd:82:ef:b4:ee:d4:fb:f4:91:58:af:5e:f2:8f:37:
                    9d:5a:9f:62:99:f9:26:31:d8:74:08:71:2f:bc:1d:
                    40:a6:43
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                F1:86:94:29:A7:F0:AF:A2:CF:CC:A2:A6:D4:63:B1:02:0A:36:7E:83
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         16:77:4d:7b:ef:89:3d:31:45:07:8f:a3:c4:ad:ed:89:a0:9b:
         b6:ab:74:59:1a:fb:7b:48:e1:e0:3c:75:73:dc:e3:e2:1b:a3:
         74:a1:0d:37:ea:ac:85:fb:1c:e0:86:f1:86:ee:78:51:fd:4d:
         58:04:8b:5c:6b:b3:06:1c:07:04:a1:c5:51:a9:d1:4c:24:42:
         7c:ef:1e:35:c5:df:00:79:44:91:a1:f5:cb:71:5b:a7:85:b1:
         f3:36:3c:75:e7:f8:d5:29:85:18:2e:ff:79:e1:eb:1f:72:24:
         6a:36:a4:17:4e:76:4d:5d:d1:85:c4:18:c3:f4:83:07:10:3f:
         7a:e2:36:33:48:1d:da:5d:08:2a:59:4f:3a:97:74:b7:d8:97:
         85:b0:b1:82:f8:46:d5:df:75:d9:56:77:34:0e:26:d5:3a:eb:
         8b:02:5e:d1:c3:fd:16:22:1f:ab:86:76:c4:cf:5b:d5:d5:bd:
         da:70:76:9e:18:bd:2f:16:c0:89:fe:cc:e0:93:63:f0:23:65:
         37:4c:6c:f5:e4:a7:fd:b2:02:86:91:6a:f5:31:b2:93:cc:33:
         87:38:57:6b:55:59:7e:ed:02:13:5d:6f:4f:15:91:ac:7e:7f:
         52:57:35:de:ec:87:38:bf:fe:7e:bd:5d:3c:ef:43:a9:d1:13:
         ab:ed:6f:ac:cf:bf:7e:e8:35:0b:92:97:08:05:78:db:68:e0:
         b1:05:2a:49:6e:00:34:71:a5:0f:5b:1c:17:47:9e:23:6f:64:
         d7:f0:93:60:12:7f:6d:0a:cd:15:e7:de:72:c4:76:86:ef:4d:
         65:c6:2a:1a:c4:35:0e:08:07:c5:ee:34:aa:9e:e1:90:d4:66:
         87:0f:1f:32:fa:21:7e:4f:01:9b:6d:19:20:ed:e5:9d:1a:ee:
         b3:e6:c4:93:4b:a4:cc:62:db:65:c1:b9:3b:05:a8:45:38:87:
         29:6d:8c:86:86:7b:c5:3d:89:85:c8:8e:f5:da:7d:c5:89:31:
         49:7b:af:9e:ff:03:89:db:ac:65:c5:5f:78:0d:cf:91:6f:19:
         6a:e4:eb:b6:d5:46:ff:3b:8c:44:cd:00:7b:3c:ed:6f:f6:79:
         61:93:12:08:58:7c:d5:02:9b:a7:4c:a0:c6:1a:f8:d9:b1:b6:
         1e:77:75:1d:24:e8:d2:ff:61:ee:a8:85:e5:1b:49:cf:3c:91:
         56:ea:e5:0e:6e:39:96:d0:d4:b7:95:25:e3:1a:a3:82:26:c8:
         3f:53:47:fe:93:10:c4:bf:91:b5:7d:40:d2:2e:22:8e:7f:e5:
         8a:4c:6e:03:04:de:f7:81:95:fc:a9:0f:31:51:ab:21:9d:20:
         06:64:c2:9e:41:db:07:86
```

Comment: Please include a dump of the certificates in question.

Comment: Mat - just edited my post to include the 3 certificates used in my post. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I just read (should have earlier) section 7.1.5 of  at [https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.3.pdf](CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.3.pdf) I'll edit my post to include this section.

Comment: Yeah, but your problem goes deeper than that (see [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/975932/171476)). openssl doesn't care about the CA/B Forum, it only checks for RFC compatibility.

Comment: Agreed - your answer spells it out, the CA/B illuminated that my usage was incorrect, that copying the 2 excluded ranges from the OpenSSL Cookbook was an error on my part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server certificate is invalid, because you have excluded its IP address in the CA cert. Here is the relevant text from RFC5280:

```
Any name matching a restriction in the excludedSubtrees
field is invalid regardless of information appearing in the
permittedSubtrees.
```

Just drop the *exluded* part of you CA certificate and everything should work. If the name constraints contain only a *permitted* section, all other names will be disallowed anyway.

[Read this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20190719142044/https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/x509-name-constraints-certificate-extension-all-you-should-know.aspx) for a good explanation on how the subtrees are processed.

Comment: Thanks @mat - I should have read section 7.1.5 of "CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.3.pdf" too. My take-away of that section:  if you don't use any permitted IP addresses, the 8 zero octets are required. If you do specify any IP addresses, remove the all-zero excluded IP ranges.   Just as you pointed out. And thanks for the link to the blog posts, my next read.

Comment: gave me the key insight. And reading the above mentioned CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements ... doc helped. I had added the static IP address to my root-ca.conf and host.cnf, thinking it would help. Sure, but I also instructed openssl to exclude all IP addresses. So the NOT_IN_NAME_SPACE makes sense to me.